# Slight pause/delay when moving

Tags: c++, sfml

I've been working on this little framework for my game today and realized that moving delays when moving around. I've used SFML before and have had the same problem, but never bothered to fix it. I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar issue and has found a solution.

Here's an example of the code which is giving me the slight pause in movement:

```
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window (sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Window");
    //window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromFile("Assets/Textures/player.png");
    sf::Sprite s;
    s.setTexture(tex);

    while (window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)){
            s.move(0.01f, 0.0f);
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(s);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

The delay/pause/whatever I'm experience is very slight but I can notice it and it's really bugging me. Just seeing the slight break in movement when none of the values alter makes my programming mind extremely sad.

Comment: Not sure about SFML specifically, but keyboard events often don't get fired until after the key is lifted or some configurable repeat-timer has activated.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard input will have a delay just like if you hold a key in Microsoft Word. To get around this, you could create a variable and set it to true when a key is pressed.

```
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window (sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Window");
    //window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromFile("Assets/Textures/player.png");
    sf::Sprite s;
    s.setTexture(tex);

    bool moving = false;

    while (window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)){
            moving = true;
        }

        if (moving) {
            s.move(0.01f, 0.0f);
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(s);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a framerate/timing issue. One frame in a 60hz game is 16.666.. milliseconds, but on Windows at least, the system clock only has a resolution of 1ms, so your delays are going to be either 16ms or 17ms. This inaccuracy results in occasional jitter as some frames are skipped (or rendered twice, in your case, giving the appearance of a short pause) even if vsync is enabled.

If you can get manual control of frame timing, e.g. by disabling `sf::RenderWindow`'s framerate limit and calling `sf::sleep` directly, one solution is to delay each frame in the sequence: 17, 17, 16, 17, 17, 16, so that the long-term average is closer to 60hz, minimizing jitter.

I have never used SFML so I can't provide any code but I hope this points you in the right direction.

You should also ensure that your monitor's refresh rate is the same as your game's framerate. SFML might already be doing this automatically.